# Passing a generic Class<T> as an argument

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

I need to pass a Class as an argument, but I only have the generic type T. How can I infer the generic Class and pass it to `fromJson()` ?

```
public class Deserializer<T> implements JsonDeserializer<JsonList<T>> {
    public T someMethod(){
        ...
        T tag = gson.fromJson(obj, ???); // takes a class e.g. something.class
        ...
    }                       
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `Deserializer` is your class, the typical way to do this is to take the `Class` as a constructor parameter:

```
public class Deserializer<T> implements JsonDeserializer<JsonList<T>> {

  public static <T> Deserializer<T> newInstance(Class<T> c) {
    return new Deserializer<T>(c);
  }

  private final Class<T> clazz;
  private Deserializer(Class<T> c) { this.clazz = c; }

  public T someMethod(){
    ...
    T tag = gson.fromJson(obj, clazz); // takes a class e.g. something.class
    ...
  }                       
}
```

Then in client code:

```
Deserializer<String> d = Deserializer.newInstance(String.class);
```

Comment: And to save us from the mind-numbing repetition of the parameter type in client code, a factory method is warmly suggested: `public static <T> Deserializer<T> newInstance(Class<T> c)`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik if you don't like mind-numbing repetition, it's best to avoid generics and Java altogether :)

Comment: Gladly, whenever that is an option---which is not very often :)

Comment: You don't need the static factory method, just use Java 7 and write:
Deserializer<String> d = new Deserializer<>(String.class)

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to Java Type Erasure, you can't.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Answer (score 3):

You can't generate it at runtime. That's why `Gson#fromJson()` requires you to pass it.